# Plotting Polynomials of best fit

Tags: matlab

I need to write a script that load some data file which contains variables x and y and fit first, second, third, fourth, and fifth degree polynomials to it. Plot the data as blue dots on a figure, and plot all five polynomial fits using lines of different colors on the same axes. This is how it *should* be:

[image]

Instead I get my polynomials separated from the data. The Data axis are([100 200 -0.2 0.2]), while my polinoms are at axis ([0 100 -0.2 0.2]).

My script:

```
%Fitting Polynomials
Dat=load('randomData.mat');
[p1,S1,mu] = polyfit(x,y,1)
[Y1,delta]= polyval(p1,x,S1,mu)
[p2,S2,mu] = polyfit(x,y,2)
[Y2,delta]= polyval(p2,x,S2,mu)
[p3,S3,mu] = polyfit(x,y,3)
[Y3,delta]= polyval(p3,x,S3,mu)
[p4,S4,mu] = polyfit(x,y,4)
[Y4,delta]= polyval(p4,x,S4,mu)
[p5,S5,mu] = polyfit(x,y,5)
[Y5,delta]= polyval(p5,x,S5,mu)
figure;
plot(x,y,'b.','MarkerSize',10)
hold on 
plot(Y1,'r')
plot(Y2,'g')
plot(Y3,'m')
plot(Y4,'c')
plot(Y5,'k')
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
title('Polynomial fitting to noisy data');
legend('Data','order 1','order 2','order 3','order 4','order 5')
hold off
```

Comment: +1 for giving your homework a try. (... and almost a -1 for posting a homework question) Good luck =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plot(Y1,'r')
```

should be

```
plot(x, Y1,'r');
```

and so on

Remember that `Y1` doesn't actually represent a polynomial relationship, it is just a vector of samples of the polynomial `p1` evaluated (via `polyval`) at the points `x`.